# How to stop this Logic App Azure: Deactivated Severity: 3 Alert?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-alerts

```
Azure Alert & Monitoring I have set Alert for Logic apps as a result for any issue happens 2 Alerts are coming 
1. Azure: Activated Severity: 3 Logic App Alert
2. Azure: Deactivated Severity: 3 Logic App Alert
```

Could someone help me like how I can stop this 2nd alert which is trigger wrongly because till that time we are not rectifying the cause of that failure which trigger the first trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your logic app first and then click the "Alerts" button --> "Manage alert rules".
[image]

Then you can delete the rules which you want.
[image]

Or you can click the rule, and then disable it.
[image]

**Update:**

Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-overview) to know about "View and resolution of fired alerts".

[image]

Comment: Thanks! but I am not want to disable it!rather for every LA failure it is shooting 2 simultaneous triggers 1. Activated trigger 2. Deactivated Trigger. The 2nd one I want to stop..How I can achieve that.

Comment: Hi @LalitDas, I'm sorry that misunderstood your requirement. But for this requirement, I'm afraid that we can not do this configuration. I have updated the answer with a document link and a screenshot for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is apparently a new preview feature called ‘[Action Rules](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-action-rules?tabs=portal)’…

> Action rules help you define alert suppression at scale with the
> ability to flexibly configure the period of suppression. In the
> previous example, the team can define one action rule on ContosoVM
> that suppresses all alert notifications for the weekend.

So I setup a new ‘action rule’ for alerts with Description contains 'Azure: Deactivated Severity'. We’ll see if this works… And once it comes out of preview the suppress rule might be expensive. We’ll have to keep an eye on this. :)